# What is the radiative cooling rate at extremely cold temperatures?

Tags: cosmology, cooling, low-temperature-physics

Consider a spherical object in empty space, in the far future where the CMB can be entirely neglected. What is the cooling rate as it approaches radiative equilibrium?

Here is what I got so far:
[The heat capacity will scale as](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/Debye.html#c2) $$C(T)=\alpha T+\beta T^3=\frac{\pi^2N_Ak^2}{2E_F}T+\frac{12\pi^4N_Ak}{5T_D^3}T^3$$ where the first term is due to electron specific heat (if the object is metallic) and the second one is the Debye phonon model. Something like this will be true even if there are other fermionic and bosonic degrees of freedom. The total energy of the object is $U(T)=(4\pi \rho/3) C(T) R^3 T$ and it will radiate at a luminosity $L(T)=4\pi R^2 \sigma T^4$. Putting it together as $U'(T)=-L(T)$ I get $(4\pi \rho R^3/4) \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha T^2+\beta T^4) = - 4\pi R^2 \sigma T^4$, or $$ \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha T^2+\beta T^4) = -  3\sigma T^4/  \rho R.$$ That gives us
$$ \frac{dT}{dt} = -  \gamma T^3/  (2\alpha +4\beta T^2)$$ where $\gamma=3\sigma/\rho R$.

The non-metallic case $\alpha=0$ has the solution $$T(t)=T_0 \exp(-(\gamma/4 \beta) t).$$ The general case has the implicit solution $\gamma t+C=(\alpha/ T^2) - 4\beta \ln(T)$ where $C=(\alpha/ T_0^2) - 4\beta \ln(T_0)$. While not very neat, it is easy to plot. For small $T$ this apparently behaves like a $T \sim t^{-1/2}$ power-law of time (can be seen by Taylor-expanding the logarithm; this is also well above the $t^{-7}$ [bound due to Nernst's law](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14538)).

Further complications:

As temperatures become low enough the wavelength of the photons will become larger than $R$, and presumably the assumptions of Stefan-Boltzman's law break since the object becomes a bad "antenna". This happens when $T \ll b/R$ (for a 1 m object this is $2.898\cdot 10^{-3}$ K, surprisingly "hot" - but presumably the relevant size scale here is the emitting subsystem rather than the entire object, and for this temperature microscopic degrees of freedom rather than the entire object matter).

This gets even more extreme when temperatures go below $cb H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda,0}}$: now the wavelength is larger than the (asymptotic) horizon size and cooling presumably is significantly slowed since the universe becomes a bad receiver.

In practice the cosmic horizon temperature ($\approx 10^{-29}$ K) will plausibly act as a lower limit.

So, what have I missed? Are there other factors determining the cooling rate for very cold objects in a cold universe?

[**Edit**: [Freeman Dyson points out](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.447) that there is an upper limit $$ P_{max}(T)=2\delta (N e^2/m\hbar^2 c^3)(kT)^3$$ on the power that can be radiated away by a system containing $N$ electrons, where $\delta\approx 1.42$ is the maximum value of the Planck radiation spectrum curve $x^3(e^x-1)^{-1}$. This limit scales as $T^3$ rather than $T^4$ because this assumes all electrons can contribute radiative power: the object is optically thin.

My spherical assumption above invalidates this thinness assumption unless it is a thin hollow sphere. In that case, we end up with $$ \frac{dT}{dt} = -  \gamma' T^2/  (2\alpha +4\beta T^2).$$ The non-metallic case now has a linearly decreasing temperature and will bump into the $t^{-7}$ Nernst limit quickly. The combined case has a messier implicit formula, but scales as $T \sim t^{-1/3}$. ]

Comment: At some point, I think you need to stop using the Debye model for phonons and just model the lowest-frequency 1 or 2 or 3 vibration modes individually. For example, a metal sphere that I can hold in my hand might have lowest-frequency vibration modes at 60Hz and 120Hz, which are in the nanokelvins.

Comment: "the object becomes a bad antenna" is a slightly weird way to think about it: It's usually more intuitive to talk about absorption rather than emission (they're related by reciprocity). So if the object is much bigger than the wavelength, say whether or not it's a blackbody, and if not, what is its emissivity. If the object is less than the wavelength, talk about its (angle-averaged) absorption cross-section as a function of wavelength.